# Convert to URL encode

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I am not really sure on whether the subject of the question is apt. Here is the question:

I am reading the contents of a page to get a reference to an URL. The content looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="/errors/validateCaptcha" name="">
                        <input type=hidden name="amzn" value="VGNBhB9ceCBo2YWErppFwA==" /><input type=hidden name="amzn-r" value="&#047;s&#047;ref&#061;nb_sb_noss?url&#061;search&#045;alias&#037;3Daps&amp;field&#045;keywords&#061;1573624098" /><input type=hidden name="amzn-pt" value="NoPageType" />
```

I am trying to read the field `amzn-r`. However as you can see it contains characters like `&#047;`,`&#061;`, etc which translate to `%2F` and `%3D`. Any way to do this via code - standard URL encode is unable to change this as I am guessing its already encoded. I am using .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Arunster's answer, you need to use both `HtmlDecode()` and `UnescapeDataString()` to convert it to straight URL. You do not need to call it through `System.Web` namespace as that would require you to include System.Web reference into your project, which is not available by default in desktop applications. Instead you can use the following alternatives:

```
string PlainURL = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString( System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#047;s&#047;ref&#061;nb_sb_noss?url&#061;search&#045;alias&#037;3Daps&amp;field&#045;keywords&#061;1573624098"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx) method that is available in System.Web library.
The usage would be to pass the string to decode the value.

So, in your case: 
`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#047;s&#047;ref&#061;nb_sb_noss?url&#061;search&#045;alias&#037;3Daps&amp;field&#045;keywords&#061;1573624098");`

yields:

```
/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=1573624098
```

I guess that's what you are looking for.